# A way to get all declared UTIs in Cocoa (Swift/Obj-C)... and/or, determining UTIs defined by App bundles?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, uti

This is actually a two-fold question, I guess. On one part, I'd like to know whether there's a neat way to enumerate all declared UTIs on a given system.

I know `lsregister -dump` is an option, given some grep and parsing on my side; however, I'm left to wonder if there isn't a better solution.

Further... I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve a list of imported/exported UTIs given an app's path. I know the reverse should be possible (i.e. finding which bundle has declared a given UTI).

One of the reasons why I'm wondering about this is because a possible solution for the first part of the question would be to iterate through all apps and retrieve their imported/exported UTIs (although I think it would probably not be a very efficient solution)

I've searched everywhere I can think of and am not really any closer to an answer. So far, it would seem it's either parse output of lsregister -dump, or try to read UTI keys directly from apps' **Info.plist** files...

Finally, in my searching I've come across a private API that *might* be of use, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it, since there's absolutely no documentation for it online... I'm talking about `"__UTCopyDeclaredTypeIdentifiers"`... maybe somebody is aware of which (if any) parameters does that function take, and/or what exactly does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Foundation
@_silgen_name("_UTCopyDeclaredTypeIdentifiers") func UTCopyDeclaredTypeIdentifiers() -> CFArray

let UTIs = UTCopyDeclaredTypeIdentifiers()
print(UTIs)
```

Should print all the UTIs that the function knows about.

Comment: Well, that solves that at least! Can't believe it was that simple... thank you very much!